How to compare two dicts with deepdiff and modify dict in place?
I've a list of two dicts and compare it with deepdiff.
How can I modify/overwrite the values in the dict1 with the modified values of the dict2 "in-place"?
import deepdiff


dict_1 = [{"id": "first", "name": "first"}, {"id": "second", "name": "second"}, {"id": "third", "name": "third"}]
dict_2 = [{"id": "first", "name": "first"}, {"id": "second modified", "name": "second modified"}, {"id": "third", "name": "third"}]


diff = deepdiff.DeepDiff(dict_1, dict_2).get('values_changed',{})
print(diff)


This results to:
{"root[1]['id']": {'new_value': 'second modified', 'old_value': 'second'}, "root[1]['name']": {'new_value': 'second modified', 'old_value': 'second'}}

How can I process the results of Deepdiff? The result should be:
dict_1 = [{"id": "first", "name": "first"}, {"id": "second modified", "name": "second modified"}, {"id": "third", "name": "third"}]

Abbendum:
If the "in-place" replacement is not working, a newly created dict_3 would also be ok.

It seems that Delta from deepdiff does what you want:
import deepdiff

dict_1 = [{"id": "first", "name": "first"}, {"id": "second", "name": "second"}, {"id": "third", "name": "third"}]
dict_2 = [{"id": "first", "name": "first"}, {"id": "second modified", "name": "second modified"}, {"id": "third", "name": "third"}]
  
diff = deepdiff.DeepDiff(dict_1, dict_2)
delta = deepdiff.Delta(diff, mutate=True)
dict_1 + delta

You can also use it without mutate=True to obtain a new object:
# ...
delta = deepdiff.Delta(diff)
dict_3 = dict_1 + delta

With this you obtain the same as dict_2. Maybe you can change the diff to only keep the values_changed if you are not interested in *_item_added from the diff.

I am impressed. You saved my day. Thanks a lot
